# Write a C program to create new array from a given array of integers shifting all even numbers before all odd numbers

Tags: c, function, declaration, return-type

There was build error in `print_array(int parray[], int size)`. Why does the error list show:

```
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    int arr_size;
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6, 9, 11 };
    arr_size = sizeof(a1) / sizeof(a1[0]);
    printf("Elements in original array are: ");
    print_array(a1, arr_size);

    int size = arr_size, index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (a1[i] % 2 == 0) {
            int temp = a1[index];
            a1[index] = a1[i];
            a1[i] = temp;
            index++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nElements in new array are: ");
    print_array(a1, arr_size);
}
print_array(int parray[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", parray[i]);
    }
    printf("%d ", parray[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: what is your exact error message? and what do you mean by default-int?

Comment: There's no definition or even declaration of `print_array`. What do you expect it do do? Giving functions good names is a good thing, but they don't write themselves.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And when asking questions about build errors, always include a full and complete copy-paste (as text) of all the error output.

Comment: Now for your problem, C and C++ are different languages and have different rules for things like function declarations. In C++ you must have an explicit return type for all functions, and all functions needs to be declared before they are used. The (partial) error message tells us you're building this as a C++ program, not C.

Comment: @klutt It's defined at the end. Unfortunately it's missing both a return type and a declaration prior to use.

Comment: Is this C or C++? Tag only one. `print_array` does not have a return type, this is not valid in C++ If C (as title suggest) then you need to compile as C, not C++

Comment: There's a standard algorithm for this: `std::partition`.

Comment: You may just need to rename your source file to `.c` or directly invoke the `c` compiler instead of the `c++` one.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Aha. I blame the indentation. :)

Answer (score 1):

C99 does not allow to use function calls for functions that were not preliminary declared. And it also does not allow to omit the function return type in a function declaration. Before the C99 it was assumed that functions with the absent return type have the return type int.

So you need 1) declare the function before its usage and 2) explicitly specify its return type as void because the function returns nothing.

Also within the function you are using a redundant printf call due to the following (unclear) loop statement

```
for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As the function does not change the array it should be declared with the qualifier `const`.

And the size of an array should have the type `size_t`.  It is the type of the value returned by the `sizeof` operator.

The loop in main can be optimized. You need not swap two elements if their indices are equal each other.

Here is your updated program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array( const int parray[], size_t size );

int main(void)
{ 
    int a1[] = { 1, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 6, 9, 11 };
    size_t arr_size = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( a1[0] );

    printf( "Elements in original array are: " );  
    print_array( a1, arr_size );

    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < arr_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( a1[i] % 2 == 0  )
        {
            if ( i != j )
            {
                int temp = a1[j];
                a1[j] = a1[i];
                a1[i] = temp;
            }                   
            j++;
        }
    }

    printf( "\nElements in new array are: " );  
    print_array( a1, arr_size );
}

void print_array( const int parray[], size_t size )
{
    for( size_t i=0; i < size; i++ )  
    {  
        printf( "%d, ", parray[i] );  
    } 

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```